# Buffers in oscillators

Tags: oscillator

Simple question.

Consider positive feedback electronic oscillators.

Imagine the amplifier I wanna use has an input impedance which is non infinite. Is it a buffer always meant to be put between the feedback loop (consider for example a Wien Bridge)?

Comment: Why would a buffer have an input impedance that is any better than the opamp plus adding a buffer would add slight delay altering the true oscillation frequency.

Comment: There are other oscillator topologies (e.g. phase shift types) requiring inverting opam based amplifiers. In this case the input impedance is just a few kohms - and a usage of a buffer helps to decouple the RC network from the amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka I have mentioned no op-amp. Imagine we have an amplifier whose input resistance is non zero. That's why I fiured I should use a buffer, so that the amplifiers doesn't drag current from the feedback bridge.

Comment: @LvW and is this a normal thing when one has input impedances that are not infinite?

Comment: The input impedance never can be infinite.The main question simply is if the input impedance is much larger than the connected source impedance. "Larger" means: At least a factor of 100 !

Comment: @zillarrezkolarrusaioa Where in your question does it state "no op-amp"? The fact that the input impedance is not infinite does not suggest that the amplifier is not an operational amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

The amplifier non-ideal input loads the feedback signal and as such attenuates it. One of the requirements of oscillation on the other hand is a loop gain equal to 1, so your amplifier has to correct for that.

You can solve it by using an extra buffer that has near infinite input impedance or you can increase the amplifier's gain slightly. Disadvantage of adding extra buffers is that the loop delay increases and the other oscillation requirement is an n × 360 degrees total phase angle (where n is an integer higher or equal to 0).

Normally the amplifier in an oscillator (like a Wien bridge oscillator) adapts its gain to the current signal amplitude.

Comment: I think, it is more correct to say that the amplifier in a WIEN oscillator must contain a non-linear element (thermistor, diodes, FET-control loop) that is able to adapt the gain to the actual amplitude in order to fulfill the oscillation condition. Without such an element there is no gain adaption but signal clipping.